# Flask cannot be executed by PHP - No module named flask

Tags: python, php, flask, terminal, virtualenv

Heey, I have a PHP script that is supposed to start a Python flask file with the `exec` command. My problem is that the file always has an error after executing:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "/opt/lampp/htdocs/memeon_data/Python-3.8.3/main.py", line 2, in from
> flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template, Response
> ImportError: No module named flask

If I run the script in the terminal, it works without problems. I did not activate the Virtualenv in the PHP script because it causes another error and I read that you no longer need it in the new versions. Maybe someone knows the answer?

PHP:

```
echo shell_exec ("python /opt/lampp/htdocs/memeon_data/Python-3.8.3/main.py 2> & 1");
```

Terminal:

```
source /opt/lampp/htdocs/memeon_data/Python-3.8.3/venv/bin/activate

python /opt/lampp/htdocs/memeon_data/Python-3.8.3/main.py
```

Comment: if you run it in terninal with `venv` then you have to do the same in PHP - create shell/bash script which runs `venv` and `main.py` and then use this script in PHP. Now you run `main.py` without `venv` so it runs Python without `flask`

Comment: BTW to runs without activating `venv` you would have to use `/full/path/venv/bin/python` instead of `python`

Comment: if you have error when you activate `venv` then show it in question (not in comment)

Comment: BTW: as for me it should be rather `2>&1` without spaces - single `&` is used to run process in background and when you add spaces then it may treat it as running in background, not redirection.

Comment: "and I read that you no longer need it" Did you test this yourself?  Try running without activating the venv and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to activate `venv` to use `python` with `Flask`

You can create bash script ie. `run.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash 
   
source /opt/lampp/htdocs/memeon_data/Python-3.8.3/venv/bin/activate
python /opt/lampp/htdocs/memeon_data/Python-3.8.3/main.py
```

and run it in PHP with `bash`

```
shell_exec("/bin/bash /opt/lampp/htdocs/memeon_data/Python-3.8.3/run.sh 2>&1");
```

Or you can skip this script and you can try to use full path to `python` which was created inside `venv/bin` - and thisp `python` should use modules installed in `venv`

```
shell_exec("/opt/lampp/htdocs/memeon_data/Python-3.8.3/venv/bin/python /opt/lampp/htdocs/memeon_data/Python-3.8.3/main.py 2>&1");
```

---

**BTW:** it should be rather `2>&1` without spaces - single `&` is used to run process in background and with spaces it may treats it as running in background or it can gives error as incorrect syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I searched for the problem for a long time. Actually I had 2>&1 but StackOverflow probably made a change.

Comment: Thank you very much have tried it now. Finally works :D